# Supposed missing brackets

Tags: fancyhdr, titlesec, brackets

I don't understand Overleaf's two complaints with the following code. It says that it has inserted a missing `{` and a missing `}`. Would someone please explain?

```
%%%%% Preamble

%%% Document class, packages

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%%% Fancy headers

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage \hspace{1cm} \leftmark}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark \hspace{1cm} \thepage}

%%% Section formatting

% Chapters

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\fillast}
{{\Huge \uppercase\romannumeral\thechapter}}
{1ex minus .1ex}
{\large \thispagestyle{empty}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}
{3pc}{*3}{*2}[3pc]

%%%%% Document

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \uppercase is wrong. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: It makes the roman numeral that numbers the chapters capital (I, II, etc.) rather than lower case (i, ii, etc.). Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Better use `\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}` to be able to get the wanted result from `\thechapter` without `\uppercase\romannumeral`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\uppercase\romannumeral\thechapter` is wrong: `\uppercase` ***needs*** to see a brace delimiting the tokens to be converted to uppercase.

You might do it with correct syntax as

```
\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral\thechapter}
```

but why doing this instead of

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
```

and using just `\thechapter` when you want to print the chapter number in Roman numerals?